# Как получить список сеансов в кинотеатрах? Нарушение авторских прав?

Tags: python, парсер, авторские-права, юридические-аспекты

Хочу в своём приложении использовать выдачу списка сеансов по кинотеатрам. Есть яндекс афиша, есть kudago сайты - реально ли парсить их данные? Это законно? Есть ли какие-то другие методы или способы получения этой информации? Планирую сохранять у себя в базе, изменять и выдавать пользователю, приложение будет ипользоваться в коммерческих целях. Подскажите, куда копать, где искать? Как поступают другие приложения, нарушают закон или парсят сами кинотеатры. Прошу помощи разобраться в этом вопросе.

Что может быть насчёт яндекс афишы? Не уверен, что их согласие по почте убережет меня от 2 лет условных за использование чужой информации, ведь у них написано, что не разрешено хранение информации. Куда обращаться?

Answer (score 3):

Подобное использование контента Яндекс Афиша вами - это явное нарушение [пользовательских условий](http://legal.yandex.ru/afisha_termsofuse/)

> 2.2. Любая информация, используемая в Сервисе, предназначена исключительно для некоммерческого использования. При этом любое копирование данных, их воспроизведение, переработка, распространение, доведение до всеобщего сведения (опубликование) в сети Интернет, любое использование в средствах массовой информации и/или в коммерческих целях без предварительного письменного разрешения правообладателя запрещается, за исключением случаев, прямо предусмотренных настоящими Условиями, условиями использования других сервисов Яндекса или документами, указанными в п. 1.2. настоящих Условий.

Так что идите к Яндексу и запросите у них API сервиса или хотя бы письменное разрешение.

P.S. Обращаться надо [сюда](http://feedback2.yandex.ru/tech/)

Answer (score 1):

> По вопросам материалов, размещенных на сайте, пишите на почту: info@kudago.com

http://kudago.com/pages/about/contacts/

С учетом того, что у них есть планы на [публичное апи](https://github.com/kudago/kudagojs) и само апи [точно реализовано](http://apptractor.ru/info/interview/vladimir-afanasev-kudago-interview.html)

> Специально для приложения мы разработали API для взаимодействия с серверами KudaGo.

проблем не будет, наоборот, они скорее всего заинтересованы в получении тестеров.

**Обновление**

[[@partizander](/users/18347/partizander)](/users/18347/partizander), что кроме формы обратной связи точную информацию вам никто не даст. Судя по тому, что апишки у них нет, предоставлять они ничего не хотят.

Comment: Хорошо, а что думаете насчёт яндекс афишы? Как бы не уверен, что их согласие по почте убережет меня от 2 лет условных за использование чужой информации, ведь у них написано, что не разрешено хранение информации. Куда обращаться?

Answer (score -1):

Информация размещена публично. Информация не является авторским произведением, ни частью защищенных баз данных, ни производным материалом (изображения, звук, видео). Таким образом парсить можно и технически возможно, посмотрите на пример Гугла и Яндекса: они у кого-то спрашивают разрешения?